# Python - Timeout rule on pdfkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, timeout, pdfkit

I was wondering if anyone knew how to implement a timeout when running pdfkit?

I am trying to loop through a large list of URLs to print pdfs for each URL page. Sometimes the loop can get hung up, however I want to just skip a URL in the loop if it takes over 30 seconds. I tried:

```
for n, i in enumerate(urllist):    
    pdfkit.from_url(i, str(directory) + "\\" + str(idnum[n]) + ".pdf", configuration=config, timeout=30)
```

The code above just ends the loop right away. This code worked perfectly without the "timeout" piece, but it took ~4 minutes to run through 10 URLs (and I need to get over 10,000)

Comment: what version of pdfkit are you using? I don't have a timeout parameter in the from_url()

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`Pdfkit` is a wrapper of [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which is usually responsible when `pdfkit` hangs on loading pages or something else. Unfortunately `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't have a timeout yet ([more here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1888)) and `pdfkit` has not fixed the problem either ([more here](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/279)).
So, no you can't use an internal timeout from `pdfkit` or `wkhtmltopdf`.

In order to surpass this problem in **Windows** (there are better solutions for LINUX) I used the `multiprocessing` package.
*Note that this code was part of bigger code and hasn't been tested as is. If it doesn't work please leave feedbak :)*

```
import pdfkit, multiprocessing

url = "a_url"

p = multiprocessing.Process(target = pdfkit.from_url, args = (url, pdf_name,)) # Create the process
p.start() # Start the process
p.join(180) # Give it a 180 sec frame to complete before you kill it
if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate() # If after 180 sec its still running, kill it

# Note that if it completes before 180 sec, the script continues (you don't wait 180 sec)
# Note that if you run pdfkit from another function declared in the script you might have problems with multiprocssing. Multiprocssing requires sometimes that functions are imported... for some reason. Just create another file and import it.
```

I didn't observe any significant change in the memory or CPU after running it for 1150 4-page pdfs

---

Multiprocessing is a bit of a heavy armor but other things that I tried did not work.
[`stopit`](https://pypi.org/project/stopit/) wasn't able to stop the process for some reason.
`signal` does not work in Windows.